# Wondering if anyone has attended ConFab in Minneapolis, MN?

Tags: usability, ux-field

Here's a link to the one coming up:
http://confab2012.com/

I'm trying to track down a Midwest based conference that goes into more UI/UX detail than something that you'd find at say, a NN/Group or Jared Spool conference. But I'm under the impression this conference is seriously geared toward web based content and strategy. ??

Answer (score 1):

You can't get much more detailed than NN/G or Spool's conferences, IMHO. I find the latter typically the best available throughout the country.

Confab looks great, though note it's about content strategy--not UX (though I tend to argue content is very much UX, but others disagree...)

If you are in MSP, you may also want to look into MIMA's annual summit event: http://www.mima.org/

While not UX specific, it covers a lot of the same ground, as well as content strategy, marketing and the like.

UofM usually has a conference or two during the year that you may want to keep an eye on.

And, finally, the Twin Cities have a long tradition of very well attended BarCamp conferences every year. Again, not UX-only, but typically quite well organized and free--so can't complain about the cost at all. ;)

Comment: Yup...I'm a huge fan of BarCamp, MinneDemo, etc. I've attended one NN/G conference, and a couple of UIE conferences and they were very good. I think I'm partly lazy about heading to NYC, but I also need to consider the cost vs. relevance. Thanks!